# Cannot implement a redirect to www url

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, redirect, http-redirect

I am setting up a new OpenCart store but have a problem with icons not appearing when I reach the site trough the URL that does not have www at the beginning.

I did a Google search and found out that I have to set up a redirect from the non www URL to the www one by modifing the .htaccess.text in my root folder. This is where the problem occurs, I cannot seem to find the right code to enter. The following is my current redirect code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eparhija\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.eparhija.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I have also tried other variants of this code bud none seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated. Also if it helps my website is www.eparhija.com

Comment: Did you rename the `.htaccess.txt` file to just `.htaccess`?

Comment: No, it's .htaccess.txt

Comment: Start by renaming it to `.htaccess`. Currently it is ineffectual due to the name. Renaming the file is part of the OpenCart installation directions.

Comment: Everything works fine now, thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `.htaccess.txt` to just `.htaccess`. Apache does not recognize the file with the `.txt` extension